# Color of operators

Tags: color

I want to change the colors of certain operators, for example making `\lim` red and `\sin` blue, in regular latex. I want to do this in the header, not in the actual text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you read the posting [How to change color of operators (lim, log, etc.)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273941/5001)? Please clarify if you want to change the color of all operators or just a few of them.

Comment: I don't recommend too much colours in text (or math) at all -- it will make the text etc. hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

For all operators, defined by `amsmath`/`mathopn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{%
  \mathop{#1\kern\z@\begingroup\color{blue}\operator@font#3\endgroup}%
  \csname n#2limits@\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x = \sin 0 \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Solution for individual colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\renewcommand*{\lim}{\qopname\relax m{\begingroup\color{red}lim\endgroup}}
\renewcommand*{\sin}{\qopname\relax o{\begingroup\color{green}sin\endgroup}}
\renewcommand*{\cos}{\qopname\relax o{\begingroup\color{blue}cos\endgroup}}

\begin{document}
\[ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x = \sin 0 = \cos \pi/2 \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with individual colors]

In both cases, the definitions are taken from package `amsopn` and the colors are added via

```
\begingroup\color{<color>}<text>\endgroup
```

The shorter `{` and `}` could also be used here for to limit the
range of the color. I prefer `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, because
it is more clear, that a group starts and ends and they are side-effect
free in math mode. The curly braces also form a subformula, which is unbreakable and might change the horizontal spacing.

Comment: Well... I am afraid \cos \pi/4 is not really zero...

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained how your redefinition of `\qopname` differs from the one proposed in [egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273978/5001) to the query [How to change color of operators (lim, log, etc.)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273941/5001)

Comment: @Matsmath: Redefine `\pi` to make the statement true :-P

Comment: @Mico Essentially in nothing; I used `\textcolor{<color>}{text}` instead of `\begingroup\color{<color>}{text}\endgroup`, which amounts to the same thing.